# Transfering an inner core model to an output model in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, instanceof

Here i've got some code to "transfer" an inner core model to an "output" model for external plugins.

For doing this, I create new instances based on the concrete subtype of a passed OldConnection and pass (with a cast) the old instance into the constructor, so i can easily maintain the inner data for getters and setters.

So, OldIncoming, OldOutgoing and OldExpected are subtypes of OldConnection. MyNewIncoming, MyNewOutgoing and MyNewExpected are subtypes of MyNewConnection. Unfortunately, I cant change the inner core model and I need concrete types in the constructors.

Code looks pretty ugly, but I just cant find a better solution for it, any ideas?

```
private MyNewConnection createIConnectedSubtypeInstance(OldConnection connection) {

    if (connection instanceof OldIncoming){
        return new MyNewIncoming((OldIncoming) connection);
    }
    if (connection instanceof OldOutgoing){
        return new MyNewOutgoing((OldOutgoing) connection);
    }
    .
    .
    .
    if (connection instanceof OldExpected){
        return new MyNewExpected((OldExpected) connection);
    }

    return new MyNewConnection(connection);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be a bunch of overloaded methods, like this:

```
private MyNewIncoming createIConnectedSubtypeInstance( OldIncoming connection ) {
  return new MyNewIncoming( connection );
}
```

That, however, works only if the caller knows what type `connection` is of, otherwise you'd have to rely on those `instanceof` checks.

In that case you could also have some mapping OldClass->NewClass and use reflection to create instances, but I doubt that would be worth the hassle unless you need a *huge*  amount of mappings.

Example:

```
Map<Class<? extends OldConnection>, Class<? extends NewConnection>> mapping; //initializing is up to you

public NewConnection  createIConnectedSubtypeInstance(OldConnection connection) {
  try {
    Class<? extends NewConnection> subtype = mapping.get( connection.getClass() );
    return subtype.getConstructor( connection.getClass() ).newInstance( connection );
  } catch( Exception e) { //you might want to catch the more specific types
    //handle appropriateley
  }
}
```

Note that this relies on the class of `connection` being mapped directly. If you map super classes you might have to check those if no mapping for the actual class of  `connection` can be found.

Additionally, this relies on the constructors of the new instances to accept exactly one parameter of the mapped class type.

Answer (score 1):

You could overload your factory method:

```
private MyNewConnection createIConnectedSubtypeInstance(OldIncoming conn) {
   return new MyNewIncoming(conn);
}

private MyNewConnection createIConnectedSubtypeInstance(OldOutgoing conn) {
   return new MyNewOutgoing(conn);
}
...
```

As Thomas points out in his answer this will only work if you call these methods with the correct static type:

```
OldIncoming a;
...
MyNewConnection b = createIConnectedSubtypeInstance(a); // will return MyNewIncoming
```

As overloading uses static binding, you cannot use `OldConnection` for a in this case. If this is not an option for you, then you will be stuck with doing instanceof at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the creation of the wrapper to `OldConnection` and its derived classes. In `OldConnection`, defined the method

```
public MyNewConnection createNewConnectiom() {
    return MyNewConnection(this);
}
```

In `OldIncoming` override with

```
public MyNewConnection createNewConnectiom() {
    return MyNewIncoming(this);
}
```

and in `OldExpected` override with

```
public MyNewConnection createNewConnectiom() {
    return MyNewExpected(this);
}
```

In that way you get rid of the branches and the casts.

Comment: If I understood correctly he cannot change the OldConnection code, that is probably why he needs the MyNewConnection wrappers in the first place.